# Can't use Python in a Virtual Environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, path, virtualenv

I recently coppied a folder with a project from one PC to another (both run Windows).
I was using a **Virtual Environment** and now, on the new PC, I'm **not able to run Python** within the Virtal Envionment anymore.

It returns this error:

```
No Python at 'C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe'
```

This is the path to Pyhon on my **old PC**.

So it searches for Python at the wrong place. Maybe I have to change the Path to Python within the Virtal Env.?

How can I get rid of this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you made sure python was installed to your path?

Comment: You are not intended to directly copy a virtual environment from one machine to another. The correct way would be to create a new virtual environment on the second machine and then use your `requirements.txt` file to install the required packages.

Comment: I can use Python outside of the Virtual Environment, so I think it is added to the path